# android update imageview from outside UI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, android

I'm trying to listen for a connection that sends a picture to my android then set this image to an image view.

the process should be done automatically to simulate a push content behavior.

this code is in TCPConHandler class

```
public void listenForIncomingImageFlag() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FlagScan = new Scanner(mySocket.getInputStream());
                    while (true) {
                        Flag = FlagScan.nextInt();
                        Log.d("FLagImage", "Flag ="+Flag);
                        if (Flag == 1) {
                            listenForIncomingImage(true);
                            Flag = 0;
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }
```

as soon as the thread running the tcp connection return a socket this function will be called . then it start another function the listenForIncomingImage.

```
public void listenForIncomingImage(boolean b) {
        check = b;
        Thread InComImage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    inComImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mySocket
                            .getInputStream());
                    MainActivity.setImage(inComImageBitmap, true);
                    check = false;
                    Log.d("Bitmap", "Bitmap receviced and sent to method");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        InComImage.start();

    }
```

thing is now to pass the image to imageUpdate function in mainactivity if i am using runOnUiThread i get an error for calling non static method.

```
public void imageUpdate() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            while(imageCheck == true){
                            myImage.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
                            imageCheck = false;}

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

so i had to start this thread when the mainactivity and block it somehow using the imagecheck boolean that is sent from the tcpConHandler class when it receive the bitmap.

doing such cause the app to overload the memory and crash is there a better way to simulate  push content behavior on android .

also is there anyway to have a function on the mainactivity that runs a thread with while(true) block inside it that can update the ui and can be static ? . or any similar implementation for such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i am using runOnUiThread i get an error for calling non static
>   method

because you will need to send `MainActivity` context to `tcpConHandler` for accessing `runOnUiThread` from non-activity class instead of calling `runOnUiThread` in static way.

create an `tcpConHandler` constructor for passing Activity context as:

```
public class TcpConHandler{
Activity activity;

public TcpConHandler(Activity activity){
 this.activity=activity;
}
//...your code here..
public void imageUpdate() {
//...your code here...
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
              // update imageView here...
          }
      });
}
```

from MainActivity create TcpConHandler object as by sending activity instance;

```
TcpConHandler tchConhandler=new TcpConHandler(this);
```

Comment: I think using handler is better option, what do you think brother..?

Comment: @Pragnani: i just replay on OP issue because he is trying to access `runOnUiThread` method in static way.Thanks for Hanlder operation

Comment: i got it working with what ρяσѕρєя K said . but i have a little problem i want to send a flag from the java client to the android then check the value of this flag to invoke another Thread. how can i separate the flag stream from the image stream

Comment: @IbrahemAhmed : for sharing flag you try it by declaring flag as static filed in any class. then u will be able to access from both classes

Comment: i am sending the flag from java server to the android